# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a number of php files in my project:

`admin.blade.php`: this files contains the admin form.

When called it show the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201

```
<h2>Please Log In To Manage</h2>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=URL::to('/admin')?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   User Name:<br />
   <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
   <br /><br />
   Password:<br />
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

In `route.php`, this call is made:

```
Route::get('/admin',array('uses'=>'student@admin'));
```

This is the function in `student.php`

```
public function admin()
{
    return View::make('student.admin');
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all() , User::rules());
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        $check = 0;
        $check = DB::table('admin')->get();
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors('That username/password combo does not exist.');
    }
}
```

I don't know much about creating an admin area, I am just trying to create it.

Comment: You're using `post` method in the form but having `get` method in the routes !

Comment: should i chnge get in my form??

Comment: Change in your routes and see what happens ;)

Comment: change your route to post , Route::post('/admin',array('uses'=>'student@admin'));

Comment: it shows the same error while i do post to both route and form     and   if i do get to both  then i come to same page again and again after submit.

Comment: you need a get route and a associating method in controller for showing the form and a post route and associating method for saving data to DB

Comment: use this Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin', 'student@admin');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I do it.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/admin', 'UsersController@getAdminLogin');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'UsersController@dashboard');
Route::post('/admin', 'UsersController@postAdminLogin');
```

**admin_login.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Id:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<h4 class="text-center">
    Welcome {{ Auth::user()->full_name }}
</h4>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
/**
 * Display the admin login form if not logged in,
 * else redirect him/her to the admin dashboard.
 *
 */
public function getAdminLogin()
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role === 'admin')
    {
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
    return view('admin_login');
}

/**
 * Process the login form submitted, check for the
 * admin credentials in the users table. If match found,
 * redirect him/her to the admin dashboard, else, display
 * the error message.
 *
 */
public function postAdminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email|exists:users,email,role,admin',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only( 'email', 'password' );

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        // Your logic of invalid credentials.
        return 'Invalid Credentials';
    }
}

/**
 * Display the dashboard to the admin if logged in, else,
 * redirect him/her to the admin login form.
 *
 */
public function dashboard()
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role === 'admin')
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

**Your Code:**

In `routes.php`, you have only 1 route, i.e.,

```
Route::get('/admin',array('uses'=>'student@admin'));
```

And there is no declaration of `post` method, hence, the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Also, in your controller, you are returning the view first and then processing the form which is not going to work at all. You first need to process the form and then return the view.

```
public function admin(){
    // Won't work as you are already returning the view
    // before processing the admin form.
    return \View::make(students.admin);
    // ...
}
```

As @Sulthan has suggested, you should use `Form Facade`. You can check out [this video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10) on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) about what `Form Facade` is and how you should use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice Solutions

Answer (score 5):

You're using `post` method in the form but you're having `get` method in the routes.

So, Change the method to `post` in your routes

**Note :**

I recommend you to make use of the default form opening of Laravel like the below given which is always the best practise

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Tips :**

[Read more on here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) and try to debug such things by comparing the methods and routes.

Form facade is not included in laravel 5 by default. You shall install it by

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

and updating in the app.php.

I have written a [blog](http://sysaxiom.com/how-to-install-illuminatehtml-in-laravel-5/) which gives a breif about this installation.

Comment: Form facade is not included in laravel 5 default, you have to install laravelcollective package

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen Thanks for reminding i will update it in the answer :)

Comment: @deepsingh Are you getting `return Input::all();` ?

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:   by doing post to routes and by using form facde . it shows this again

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct form and routes, Also try to change the method to `get` (Just a blind way)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen .. i didnt get you. .. mean how return Input::all();

Comment: @deepsingh I mean to say `return Request::all();`

Comment: ErrorException in Factory.php line 91:
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\again\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210 and defined.. it shows this error now.. can you plz help me in this @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: @deepsingh You still have the issue ?

Comment: no thanks.. i have solved this .. bt i have other issues plz go on this link.. and read the comnts and then make me reply brother   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233896/laraval-5-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-intern-user?noredirect=1#comment50467337_31233896

Answer (score 2):

In Routes **web.php**
Your code is

```
Route::get('/admin',array('uses'=>'student@admin'));
```

which is wrong.
Actually submitting data in POST method its array of data so you need to route through post instead of get.
so correct code is

```
Route::post('/admin',array('uses'=>'student@admin'));
```

Follow this tutorial form Laracast it might helpful,
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/16

Answer (score 1):

In `routes.php`, replace `Route::get` by `Route::post`.

Answer (score 0):

You have no post route for your form data posting , use route match function for both http verb (get & post). use this

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin', 'student@admin');

Also you need to change your admin method,

```
public function admin(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('get')){
        return \View::make('student.admin');
    } else {
    // your validation logic
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. by using match.. error gone.. but it is returning to the admin login page after submitting the button  rather than going to view page... what should i do of this

Comment: because you are returning the login view at 1st line in admin method, you should use 2 different methods or use condition to check the request type , & then process it

Comment: i mean it must go to home page... bt it is not going there

Comment: so what should i do of that line.. i am not getting.. should i delete that line or place it somewhere else.. or tell me the edited version of that plz.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found.. what of this @Nehal hasnayeen

Comment: You have to import user class ,where is your user class,i assume it is in app folder,if it is then import it like these : use App\User;

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1994: it shows this now

Comment: give full error message, it must be showing which method

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1994:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::rules().. it says this

Comment: problem is in this line $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), User::rules()); there is no rules method,rather you should give an array of rules for validation

Comment: omg. lot of errors . it shows this this now.   ErrorException in Factory.php line 91:
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\again\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210 and defined

Comment: i told you to give an array of rules for validation , read carefully previous comments