# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table X doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error in Laravel 5:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'intern.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from users where username = admin limit 1)

config/database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'intern',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

The function admin is called for admin page, and database table is mentioned in it as admin because there are many tables in it.

```
    public function admin(Request $request){

           if($request->isMethod('get')){
           return \View::make('student.admin');
        } else
    {


        $check=0;
        $check=\DB::table('admin')->get();
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');



     $data=array(
     'username'=>$request->get('username'),
     'password'=>$request->get('password')
    );

    if(\Auth::attempt($data))
    {
        return redirect::intended('student/index');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('student/admin');
    }


        }   



       }
```

Form is here:

```
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
  <h2>Please Log In To Manage</h2>
  {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/admin')) !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


    User Name:<br />
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

     <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />


 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: What auth driver do you use?

Comment: 'driver' => 'eloquent',  this one

Comment: The error message says, that there is no users table in the database. Have you created that table? Either manually or by running "php artisan migrate"?

Comment: i have created the admin table manually .. not the user table.. i dont know why it is saying about user table

Comment: Auth::attempt() tries to load user from the database. Eloquent driver uses User model to do that, you can change the model used in config/auth.php

Comment: so i change it like this     'table' => 'admin', or i need to change anything else also??

Comment: "table" field is used by database driver, "model" is used by Eloquent driver. So if you have Eloquent Admin model, then change model config value to that class, otherwise switch to database auth driver and change table config value to admin

Comment: i dont have eloguent admin model.. and even i dont know much about it.. and i changed the config table to admin.. but now it shows  the same error again

Comment: Change also driver to database: 'driver' => 'database',

Comment: but problem is that.. even after giving right password and username.. it is going in this part     else
    {
        return redirect('student/admin');
    }

Comment: @deepsingh How are you storing the password in the db ? Are you hashing it or storing it in plain text ?

Comment: @deepsingh No, you should not store as a plain text, you should hash it before you store, then only laravel can able to re-hash it and make authentication. You want to know how you can do hash and store password ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen and Deep. Minor item of feedback: comments are to aid the understanding of a question, and not general chat. Above, there are clarifications to the question (should be question edits) or general chat ("am writing an answer", "please help", "let me check") that are not necessary. I've flagged them as "too chatty" but if you can reduce excessive comments, it will help other readers who want to understand the current state of the question (less for them to read). Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Thanks :) I have got the point and follow the same in future ! Thanks for your feedback :) Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should hash and create the User details to make the coloumn ready for authentication.

Here i have given the steps to achieve it.

**Step 1 :** Get the Input

`$UserData = Input::all();`

**Step 2 :** Create the entry - Inserting into User Table

`User::create($UserData);`

**Note :**

You should have these following coloumns in your `users` table

1. email,
2. password
3. created_at
4. updated_at

**Additional Setup :**

Have this line in your User.php (Model)

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];
```

**Here's my tiny login code for you which would simple enough for you**

Have a try over this if you wish

```
$email = $this->request->input('email');
$password = $this->request->input('password');
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) #If the Credentials are Right
{
 return redirect::intended('student/index'); #Your Success Page
}
else
{
 return redirect('student/admin'); #Your Failure Page
}
```

**Recommendation :**

I would also recommend to [validate](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation) the user input before creating

**Additional Note :**

If you see your table and if you password is something like encrypted and it means that you're done ;)

Comment: i check the password in php my admin.. but it comes in same way.. not encrypted

Comment: You use this code to insert data `User::create($UserData);` ?

Comment: @deepsingh That's what i said, You should not do that at first step. Laravel can't identify plain text password. Laravel will consider only hashed password and you can do that only by `User::create($UserData);`

Comment: but when i have inserted the data manually in php my admin... then where should i put this code. and how tell me

Comment: @deepsingh You should not insert directly insert into phpmyadmin. You should prepare a register/insert form then and then create a controller and have this code there..

Comment: If you want to test instantly, here's a hashed password `$2y$10$nTcLwPJXvWkcd1g.xWxYueeJeSDarKm7nGOWDX/tHFc8Sv.kQyFJW` which stands for `adminadmin` . Put this inside the password field to test it instantly

Comment: nah .. it not working and my password is admin and username bis admin

Comment: @deepsingh How did you hashed your password `admin` ?

Comment: i havent hashed my password admin.. i dont know about that

Comment: That's what i said my friend. Laravel can't able to identify the unhashed password for authentication. I simply hashed a password for you for testing purpose.

Comment: Just put that hashed password inside your password column of your `users` table and enter the password as `adminadmin` and test that. Then i can able to explain you how it works :)

Comment: can you please hash the "admin" word for me... so i can check it

Comment: do u have skype.. so i can show u my screen and can make me understand better code..  tell me if u have.. i will email u.

Comment: i have checked the adminadmin even also as hashed form.. but .. still it is not working

Comment: Cool, That's the point. Here's the hash for admin `$2y$10$lVoViB8RyqIF5NdsNEf85e4Z/fwNzFrLVez6vsOVJUc29NXPbXbwe` for `admin`, Look at my profile ;)

Comment: @deepsingh: we try to discourage question-askers from requesting email/VOIP details, as it looks like you want a free private support channel. It is much better to receive help in public, so people can benefit from the Q&A in the future.